# What is the propper way to break hanging scaner?

Tags: go

This is an example from Go docs, that just hangs waiting for STDIN input:

```
 scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
 for scanner.Scan() {
     fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
 }
 if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
     fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
 }
```

The same thing happens if you read an empty file.

What is the propper way to break hanging scanner?

The only solution that comes to mind is a periodic check to see if scanner has received new data.
There is a feeling that I'm missing some nonsense and the solution is actually obscenely simple and obvious.

Comment: You cannot reliably break from within a read call on stdin (unless it is closed externally). Either break on some known condition before continuing the loop, or leave the goroutine running.

Answer (score 1):

You can't end (terminate) a `Scanner.Scan()` call.
You loop until [`Scanner.Scan()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Scan) keeps returns `true`. `Scanner.Scan()` will keep returning `true` as long as lines (be them empty or not) are successfully read. It returns `false` if end of input is reached or reading fails.

So for you to exit the loop, you have to "transmit" end of input signal on your terminal. This can be done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on unix systems, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows.

Of course you can modify the loop body, and add a condition (`if`) to terminate if a certain input is entered, e.g. `exit`:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println(line)
    if line == "exit" {
        break
    }
}
```